# Setting custom denyCallback even when returning false from matchCallback with Yii2 behaviours

Tags: php, yii, permissions, yii2, user-permissions

I'm using `Yii2` and utilising their [behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html) within my controllers.

I am building my own permissions system and because the permissions are rather complex I need to make use of a [matchCallback](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accessrule.html#$matchCallback-detail).

Here is an example:

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['view'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['view'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        return Yii::$app->authManager->can($rule, $action);
                    }
                ],      
                // everything else is denied
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Now, unfortunately the way the `matchCallback` works is by returning `true` or `false` on if it should *continue* to execute the rule, rather than being able to return true or false of they are allowed or not.

So if I return `false` that it shouldn't continue (and hence disallow them) then I am unable to customise the `denyCallback` as it quits executing the rule.

Is there anyway I can customise the `denyCallback` even if I return `false` from the `matchCallback` - or should I be handling my situation in a different way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define `denyCallback` as property of `AccessControl` instead of defining it in `AccessRule`. It will get called if `allow` after rule check returns *null*. It has the same signature as `denyCallback` in `AccessRule`:

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['view'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['view'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        return Yii::$app->authManager->can($rule, $action);
                    }
                ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action){...}
            // everything else is denied
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

As another option you can extend `AccessRule` class and override `allows()` method to return *false* instead of *null* when match check fails, and your rule's `denyCallback` will be called then:

```
class MyAccessRule extends AccessRule
{
    public function allows($action, $user, $request)
    {
        $allows = parent::allows($action, $user, $request);
        if ($allows === null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $allows;
        }

    }
}
```

`matchCallback` only determines should rule be applied or not, and if `matchCallback` returns *true* and other parameters are match(e.g. *roles*, *verbs* etc.), call to `allows()` will return rule's `allow` parameter *true* or *false* as you set it in configuration. And if `matchCallback` returns *false*  - `allow` will be *null* and rule's *denyCallback* will not be called, but *AccessControl* `denyCallback` will be called instead if it is set in configuration.

As you mentioned in the comments third option is to make `allows()` return result of callback.

```
class MyAccessRule extends AccessRule
{
    public $allowCallback;
    public function allows($action, $user, $request)
    {
        if(!empty($this->allowCallback) {
            return call_user_func($this->allowCallback);
        }
        $allows = parent::allows($action, $user, $request);
        if ($allows === null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $allows;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok cool. So if extend it and return `false` from my `matchCallback` it essentially changes `allow` into `false` correct? ...and if I return `true` from my `matchCallback` it won't touch the `allow` setting? I guess that could work; though what would be great if they allowed you to set a callback as the value of `allow`. :)

Comment: Sorry, my extra questions above were based around if I extended it like you referenced: `class MyAccessRule extends AccessRule` as I would prefer to be able to customize each one if needed. However, I may just end up seeing if I can extend it so it can take a callback as the value of `allow`.

Comment: @Brett That's an option too )

Comment: Thanks for all the options. I will surely use one of them! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well ... using `Yii::$app->authManager->checkAccess($uerId,$permissionName,$dataToPassInArray)` is quite simple then.If you wanna current logged in user's id , you should get current user's instance by `Yii::$app->user->identity` at first.Properties of logged in user instance depends on the user model you use (e.g. `yii\web\User` or other customized ones).

Comment: I mean using this in the body of 'matchCallback' => function($rule, $action ){ /* my code here, as they must  return what `checkAccess()`  gets */ }